# Compilation error failable initializer of struct

Tags: swift, struct, compiler-errors, initializer

I have to initialise values by reading from JSON file hence was writing failable initiazer. Please review following code and provide suggestions

```
struct ViewModel {
    var cards : EmployeeData

    init?() {

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "EmployeeData", ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                self.cards = try decoder.decode(EmployeeData.self, from: jsonData)

            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}


struct EmployeeData : Decodable {
    var employeeCards : [EmployeeCards]

    struct EmployeeCards : Decodable {
        var  title : String
        var description : String
        }
}
```

Comment: You must provide a branch for when `if let path` fails.

Comment: A failable initializer is nonsense in this case. Files in the application bundle are required at compile time and cannot be changed at runtime. Use `try!` and force unwrap optionals. The code must not crash. If it does you made a design mistake. And there is a `url(forResource` API.

Comment: Adding fail branch to if let helped to get rid of compilation error.

Comment: Using url(forResource ) is clean solution for code at hand however failable initiazer is required to handle failure due to json parsing.

Comment: There are unit tests to evaluate the JSON parsing. That's clearly a compile / design time issue. You are discouraged from checking it at runtime